# Tanimoto Coefficient using Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-segmentation

I need to calculate Tanimoto Coefficient. I don't know what's wrong in my code. I have 2 nearly similar images. But the value obtained using my code indicates that the two images are highly dissimilar. Kindly help me with my code.

```
%Tanimoto coeff
I=imread('sliver3.jpg');
J=imread('ref5.jpg');
figure,imshow(I),title('Original');
figure,imshow(J),title('Reference');
inter=intersect(I,J,'rows');
uni=union(I,J,'rows');
si=size(inter);
su=size(uni);
tc=si/su
```

I attach three images here. First one is the segmented output. Second is a reference image.Third is also a reference but which is highly dissimilar. So, the output must be that, first and second must be nearly similar and first and third must be highly dissimilar. But I'm getting the opposite.

**For first two images, tc =0.4895
For first and third images, tc=0.5692**

Kindly help me out.

[image: Segmentation output]
[image: Correct Reference]
[image: Dissimilar Reference]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use the `sum()` function on union and intersect instead of `size()` since the Tanimoto Coefficient is the "summation of the intersect"/"summation of the union"